# Sign of $\cosh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))\cosh(\frac{t}{2})-\cosh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))-\cosh(\frac{t}{2})$ on $t\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For fixed $\theta>0$  we consider the function:

$f(t)=\cosh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))\cosh(\frac{t}{2})-\Big(\cosh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))+\cosh(\frac{t}{2})\Big)$ for all $t\ge 0$

I want to study the sign of  $f$ in $[0,+\infty[$

I calculated the derivative of  $f$ and i find :

$f'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\cosh(\theta)sh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))\Big(\cosh(\frac{t}{2})-1\Big)+\frac{1}{2}\sinh(\frac{t}{2})\Big(\cosh(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta))-1\Big)\ge 0$ for all  $t\ge 0$

Then $f(t)\ge f(0)=-2$

But i woud like to find  $t$ for which $f(t)\ge 0$ and $t$ for which $f(t)\le 0$

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is $ch(\theta)$ the same as $(\exp(\theta)+\exp(-\theta))/2$?

Comment: exactly it is $cosh(\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Key-tool: $\cosh(2x)=1+2\sinh^2(x)$

This is a nice example where computing the derivative only obscures things...

Let $u=\cosh\theta$, then, for every $t$, $$f(4t)=\cosh(2ut)\cosh(2t)-\cosh(2ut)-\cosh(2t)=4\sinh^2(ut)\sinh^2(t)-1$$ hence $f(4t)$ has the sign of $g(t)-1$ where $$g(t)=2\sinh(ut)\sinh(t)$$ The function $g$ increases from $g(0)=0$ to $g(+\infty)=+\infty$ hence, for every $u$, there exists a unique $t^*$ such that $$g(t^*)=1$$ Thus, $f(0)=f(\frac14t^*)=0$, $f(t)<0$ for every $t$ in $(0,\frac14t^*)$, and $f(t)>0$ for every $t$ in $(\frac14t^*,+\infty)$, where $t^*>0$ is the unique solution of the identity

> $$2\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)\sinh(t^*)=1$$

Comment: and can us determine explicitly the solution of $2\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)\sinh(t^*)=1$?

Comment: Of course not, if by "determine", you mean to find an analytical formula of $t^*$. But bounds on $t^*$ can be deduced from this.

Comment: ok how can us bound $t^*$?

Comment: Sure you have no idea on your own? This might be the time for you to grab a piece of paper and a pencil, otherwise people will start to think you take the site for a free answering machine...

Comment: For example, if your aim is to show that $f(t)>0$ for every $t\geqslant\theta/\cosh\theta$, all you have to check is that $$4\theta/\cosh\theta>t^*$$ that is, that $$2\sinh(4\theta)\sinh(4\theta/\cosh\theta)>1$$ for example under the condition that $$\cosh\theta>2$$ And *that* is not a Herculean task, is it?

Comment: i tried to write $2\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)\sinh(t^*)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{\cosh(\theta)t^*}-e^{-\cosh(\theta)t^*})(e^{t^*}-e^{-t^*})$ and then dvollop all but i didn't find the bounds

Comment: Did you try to plot the graph of the function $$h(\theta)=\sinh(4\theta)\sinh(4\theta/\cosh\theta)\ ?$$

Comment: no i don't know how to use any program to plot the function

Comment: Try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sinh(4x)sinh(4x%2Fcosh+x)).

Comment: when $cosh(\theta>2$ we have $2\sinh(4\theta)\sinh(4\theta/\cosh\theta)\le 2\sinh(4\theta)\sinh(2\theta)$ but how we can prove  that $2\sinh(4\theta)\sinh(4\theta/\cosh\theta)>1$?

Comment: the plot tells us that $h(\theta)\ge 0$ if $\theta\le 3$ is that right?

Comment: for the general case $2\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)\sinh(t^*)=1\ge \cosh(\theta)t^*t^*=\cosh(\theta)(t^*)^2$ then $(t^*)^2\le \frac{1}{ch(\theta)}$ then $t^*\le  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ch(\theta)}}$ Right?

Comment: Actually $h(\theta)\geqslant0$ everywhere (and we do not care). The question is where $h(\theta)>\frac12$ and this holds true for $\theta>\theta^*$ with $\theta^*\approx0.747$. The upper bound of $t^*$ that one reaches with the approach in your comment is $t^*\leqslant1/\sqrt{2\cosh\theta}$ and it is of the correct order when $\theta\to\infty$.

Comment: we have also $2\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)\sinh(t^*)=1\le 2\sinh^2(\cosh(\theta)t^*)$ then $1\le \sqrt{2}\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)$ then $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}\le\sinh(\cosh(\theta)t^*)$ then $\frac{1}{\cosh(\theta)}Argsinh(\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}})\le t^*$ right?

Comment: Hence $\frac{1}{\cosh(\theta)}Argsinh(\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}})\le t^*\le  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2ch(\theta)}}$?

Comment: ?? The number $t^*$ is **defined** by the identity $g(t^*)=1$. Sorry but instead of firing a succession of comments like you are doing, why not turn to a careful and slow reading of my post?

Comment: I change the notations: for all $t>0$ we note: $\begin{align*}v(t)=\frac{\sinh\big(\frac{t}{2}\cosh(\theta)\big)}{\cosh(\theta)},&A(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\cosh^2(\theta)v^2(t)+1}-1}{\cosh^2(\theta)}-\Big(\cosh\Big(\frac{t}{2}\Big)-1\Big), \\&k(t)=-\ln\Big(1-\frac{2A(t)}{u(t)+\sinh(t)+A(t)}\Big)\end{align*}$ is there a simplification for $k(t^∗) $ or is it possible to find a constant $c>0$ such that $k(t^∗)≥c$?

Comment: You know what? Your approach to comment threads is flawed (and  regret having engaged you in this thread). If you have another problem than the one you asked and that I solved, please post another question.

Comment: I already post it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503964/prooving-an-inequality-for-t0 but i didn't find any help

Answer (score 0):

So your $f(t) = \cosh(t/2)\cosh(At/2) - (\cosh(t/2) + \cosh(At/2)$ where $A=\cosh(\theta)>1$, and you want to find $t$ solving $$\cosh(At/2) = \frac{\cosh(t/2)}{\cosh(t/2)-1}.$$ I cannot believe there is a closed form solution, except possibly for a few special values of $\theta$.  But the monotony of $f$ should make numerical calculations easy and accurate, if that is any consolation. Or perhaps your $\theta$ is very small, or very large, and asymptotic expansions in powers of $\theta$ would be useful to you.

Comment: if $\theta$ verifies $ch(\theta)\ge 2$ is it true that $f'(t)\ge 0$ for all $t\ge 0$?

Comment: 1. I believe so, but 2. didn't you already verify this pour tout $t\ge0$?

Comment: sorry i mean if $θ$ verifies $ch(θ)≥2$ do we have   $f(t)\ge 0$  for all $t\ge \frac{\theta}{ch(\theta)}$?